# How to use dynamic allocation instead of static int?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, static, allocation

```
 int* asciiCode(char c1, char c2){
   static int asciiCode[126];
   /code/
   /code/
   return asciiCode;
 }
```

Can I use allocation instead of static int for this situation ? I don't know exactly the number of elements of above pointer array ? If yes, how can I do that ?

Comment: `May I can use allocation`..what allocation? dynamic? why?

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: yes, dynamic allocation, sorry for this

Comment: Which problem are you _actually_ trying to resolve ? Looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: `static int asciiCode[126];` --> `int *asciiCode = malloc(sizeof(int)*NUM_OF_ELEMENTS);` Take care of `malloc` returned value `!= NULL`

Comment: There is no "pointer array", and it's basically impossble to understand what the code should do.

Comment: I suggest a better solution is to pass pointer that you return as parameter and make a caller to do the allocation. It is usually better to make the caller function take care of the buffer, than the callee (actually, if you allocate in callee function, you should deallocate in caller, so they both take care of memory)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use allocation instead of static int for this situation ?

Yes, as long as some routine also `free()` the allocated memory.

> I don't know exactly the number of elements of above pointer array ?

There is no pointer array in your code. If you mean the `int` array, the amount of items appear to be 126. Which seems strange, old 7-bit ASCII has 128 symbols, not 126.

> If yes, how can I do that ?

With `malloc` then return a pointer.

Comment: I think that standard 7bit ASCII has 128 symbols [ASCII](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Comment: @sg7 Hmm yeah actually 0 counts as a symbol too, probably. I'll edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example which you may find useful. `array` is allocated and the used in subsequent calls in order to emulate the use of static array to hold the values between the calls.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* asciiCode(char c1, char c2, int *asciiCodeArr, int size ){
   int static counter = 0;

   if(asciiCodeArr==NULL)
   {
     asciiCodeArr = (int *) malloc( sizeof(int)* size);
     if(!asciiCodeArr) return NULL;
   }

   printf("c1=%c ",c1);
   printf("c2=%c ",c2);

   asciiCodeArr[counter] = c1;
   counter = counter + 1;

   asciiCodeArr[counter] = c2;
   counter = counter + 1;

  return (asciiCodeArr);
 }

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int *array=NULL;
    int size = 128; // To Hold 128 - 7bits Standard ASCII characters 

    array = asciiCode('1', '2', array, size);
    if(!array){
        printf("allocation error!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // array = 
    asciiCode('3', '4', array, size);

    printf("\narray content in hex: ");    
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
       printf("%X ", array[i]);
    }

   free(array);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
c1=1 c2=2 c1=3 c2=4 
array content in hex: 31 32 33 34
```